# NSTextView: replace all tabs

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I have a `NSTextView` where I would like to use spaces instead of tabs. I though I would `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` in `textStorageWillProcessEditing:` of my `textview delegate` but it doesn't work (undo breaks).

Please, does anyone know how to implement such functionality? Is there other way of doing it?

Edit: this is what I have in the `textStorageWillProcessEditing:` method:

```
ts = [notification object];
[[ts mutableString] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\t"
                                    withString:@"  "
                                       options:NSLiteralSearch
                                         range:[ts editedRange]];
```

Comment: I suspect you're really close in terms of getting this to work. If you have a handle to the text storage of the text view, you can do the "`replaceOccurrencesOfString:`" call on that.  Modify this question to show the code of what you've done so far and if it's still not working, I'll try to answer it for you (if somebody else doesn't come along and answer it first).

Comment: How exactly does this break undo? Your code seems to work fine for me.

Comment: When I hit "a", "tab", undo, redo, then there is "a_", and not "a__". More precisely, the spaces are there but the curson moves to wrong location. Also, when I paste longer text, undo will erase just part of it.

Comment: When I paste in "tab", "tab", "a", there is "____a". Undo, and there is "_a".

Comment: I see, interesting question that I unfortunately don't know the answer to.

Comment: Instead of handling this with NSTextStorage, it might be better to handle it with NSTextView. You could look at `-textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:`, `-textDidChange:`, or `-textView:didCheckTextInRange:types:options:results:orthography:wordCount:` in NSTextViewDelegate.

Comment: @noa: I tried the first option but when I hit "a", the textview displays "aa".

Comment: noa: see above, that's the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the the keyUp: method.
If the event.keyCode == keycodefortabwhichidontknow :)
then you could insert four spaces.

And if else, of course just call [super keyDown:theEvent];